# For an email newsletter should I use double br tags to reduce some inline code?

Tags: html, email, html-email

Since I'm styling inline using `<span>` or `<p>` tags should I maybe just go real old school and use `<br><br>` to break paragraphs instead of closing and reopening the `<p>` tag each time?

For example here's a snippet of code that I currently have and its just so redundant. I know that's the nature of having to code inline but seems like I might be able to reduce some noise by doing `<br><br>`

```
<p style="font-size: small; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif">Selection of the 200 New &amp; Recently updated companies over the last month. Click on the company name for up-to-date business information.</p>
<p style="font-size: small; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif">Company Name, FL provider of Category was updated on 2/12/2013</p>
<p style="font-size: small; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif">Company Name, TX provider of Category was updated on 2/13/2013</p>
<p style="font-size: small; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif">Company Name, AK provider of Category was updated on 2/15/2013</p>
```

Is there a downside to switching some of this out when applicable for `<br><br>`? Email client support or anything like that?

Comment: Tables are the only thing that is supported very well when it comes to newsletters - use tds and spans - using empty tds to create larger breaks between lines where you need.

Comment: @mikevoermans -  that's true for layout (avoiding `float`, `position`, etc) but you can safely use block-level elements as long as you're avoiding those types of layouts (and `margins` are inconsistently supported)

Comment: @Ben you can use block level elements such as div and p - but I avoid them as well because I've found that web based browsers add default styling to them that I don't want to override. i.e. Gmail turning text purple! - ugh

Comment: @mikevoermans I'm using tables for the majority of the layout. I suppose I could just keep adding small tables inside of cells for any section that would require paragraph tag. You really find its that much more compatible? Most things Ive read say now everything supports the p tag

Comment: @Ryan Don't misinterpret what I'm saying. I'm not saying p tags DON'T work - I'm saying I recommend tds and spans because web based email clients have styles that cascade into them. In my experience no client has added any default styles to spans or tds. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dyuxH

Comment: @mikevoermans okay thanks for the info. where do you stand on BR tags? Never use them or only if I want a single carriage return?

Comment: @Ryan - I use them when I'm putting returns between blocks of copy - but not for larger spacing / layout things. I guess I think of it - if this didn't show up - is it a dealbreaker? Tables have never failed me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Feel free to use the line break tags, you quite rightly have already identified the potential for reducing your markup this way, and there are no disadvantages to doing this. Every email client and web client supports them, and they're more reliable than using margins on paragraph tags, since margins aren't supported comprehensively across all systems.

Reference: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I did upvote this answer - but I want to say a version or two of Lotus notes doesn't support the br tag. Trying to find a support table... http://mytechsolutions.blogspot.com/2010/10/line-breaks-does-not-appear-in-html.html and a comment on: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1893/a-css-solution-to-image-blocki/

Comment: I should also clarify, this is only in reference to creating "paragraph" style spacing in blocks of text. If it's more complex than that I completely endorse the using of tables and tds to get the spacing you require.

I may be mis-remembering my Lotus notes issues, but I thought Lotus adhered to HTML rather than XHTML, which caused confusion with the closure of a br tag.

Answer (score 6):

I use double `<br>` tags between all text. It is the most consistent option for email.

You'll need to pair it with a `&nbsp;` though at the top and bottom of your text as it can in some clients (Outlook I think) will compress empty lines. Here is an example:

```
<td>
&nbsp;<br>
The no break space is needed above and below the text where it meets the table cell.
<br><br>
double br's between paragraphs are the best way to do it.
<br><br>
You need 1 no break space per line at the bottom (and top) so that Outlook doesn't remove the text row.
<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
</td>
```

This is the quickest way, but limits you to multiples of your line-height. Another option is to use padding:

```
<td style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:30px;">
The no break space is needed above and below the text where it meets the table cell.
<br><br>
double br's between paragraphs are the best way to do it.
<br><br>
You need 1 no break space per line at the bottom (and top) so that Outlook doesn't remove the text row.
</td>
```

Assuming the line-height was set at 15px, both these methods will produce the same results and are widely supported in all major email clients.